# Get argument expression before evaluation

Tags: javascript, arguments, eval, expression

I'm trying to create an assert method in Javascript.  I've been struggling with arguments.callee.caller and friends for a while, but I can't find a way to reliably get the full text of the calling function and find which match in that text called the current function.

I want to be able to use my function like this:

```
var four = 5;
function calculate4() { return 6; }

assert(4 == 2 + 3);
assert(4 == four);      
assert(4 == calculate4());
assert(4 != 3 && 2 < 1)
```

and get output like this:

Assertion 4 == 2 + 3 failed.
Assertion 4 == four failed.
Assertion 4 == calculate4() failed.
Assertion 4 != 3 && 2

Right now, I can't get much beyond `Assertion false failed.` which isn't very useful...

I'd like to avoid passing in extra parameters (such as `this`) because I want to keep the assert code as clean as possible and because it will be typed many, many times. I don't really mind making it a string, but I'm concerned about issues of scoping when trying to eval() that string.  If I have no other options, or if my concerns are ill-founded, please say so.

I'm running this in an .hta application on Windows, so it's really jscript and I have full access to the filesystem, ActiveX etc. so system specific solutions are fine (as long as they don't require Firebug etc.).  However, I'd prefer a general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reliable way you can do this passing only a single argument.  Even with `eval`, the variables used would be out of scope.  Parsing `arguments.caller` would work if `arguments.caller` made only one call to `assert`, by searching for it and parsing the argument expression.  Unfortunately, none of the proprietary tools available to you will help.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my fears.  I'll let this go a few hours longer, and if no one has a better solution, I'll accept it.

Comment: @reem: no worries :-) I honestly wish this weren't the case, as I was writing a console application for Internet Explorer recently and something like this would have come in useful.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following function, which allows me to optionally duplicate the text of the assertion as a second argument.  It seemed simplest.

```
function assert(expression, message) 
{
    if (!expression) {
        if (message + "" != "undefined" && message + "" != "") {
            document.write("<h2>Assertion <pre>" +
                            message + 
                           "</pre> failed.</h2><br>");
        } else {
            document.write("<h2>Assertion failed.</h2><br>");
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe that helps someone.  There are probably better methods available, but this worked for me.

Note that I've only been programming in Javascript for three days, so there's probably a number of improvements that could be made.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible, at least in browsers and Node.js. I don't know about .hta applications.

Modern browsers, Node.js **and hopefully your environment** put a [`stack` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack) on error objects, containing a stack trace. You can construct a new error, and then parse out the file path to the file containing the `assert()` call, as well as the line number and column number (if available) of the call. Then read the source file, and cut out the `assert` expression at the given position.

1. Construct an `error`
2. Parse `error.stack`, to get `filepath`, `lineNumber` and `columnNumber`
3. Read the `file` at `filepath`
4. Cut out the bits you want near `lineNumber` and `columnNumber` in `file`

I've written such an assert function, called [yaba](https://github.com/lydell/yaba), that might get you going.